# Can't show folder selection dialog in Electron

Tags: node.js, electron

How can I show a folder selection dialog in NodeJS or ElectronJS?

Currently, I'm using `nw-dialog`:

```
const dialog = require('nw-dialog')
dialog.openFileDialog(function() {
    alert('test')
})
```

However, I am getting an exception:

> ReferenceError: `document` is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`nw-dialog`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nw-dialog) is intended to be used with [`nw`](https://nwjs.io/), not with Electron.

If you want to open dialogs in Electron, you should use Electron's [`dialog`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md) module:

```
const {dialog} = require('electron')
console.log(dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openFile', 'openDirectory', 'multiSelections']}))
```